# How to properly wait when recoloring buttons

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait

I am new to Android app development, and I am trying to create a simple Simon Says game with buttons.  Right now when I show the sequence I color the button white, try (and currently fail) to wait 500ms, and then color the button back to its original color.

The problem is that either how I am waiting does not work how I expect and causes multiple buttons to be white at the same time, or it crashes the app with no exceptions that I can see in the console.  I have tried using Handler.postDelayed() and now I am trying to use a Timer object which actually doesn't do the color changing at all and will crash after creating a new game.

Here is my current Java code:

```
 package mpeterson.SimonSays;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import java.util.*;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ArrayList<Integer> sequence;
        private int curPos;
        private boolean waiting;
        private Random rand;
        private Button start;
        private Button[] buttons = new Button[4];//green,red,blue,yellow
        private int[] colors = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW};
        private Timer t = new Timer();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green);
        buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red);
        buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue);
        buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yellow);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        //System.out.println("Initialized");
    }
    public void startGame(View view){
        sequence = new ArrayList<>();
        curPos = 0;
        rand = new Random();
        waiting = false;
        start.setText("Restart Game");
        for(Button b : buttons) {
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        try{
            //System.out.println("to nextInSeq");
            nextInSeq();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void nextInSeq() throws InterruptedException {
        //System.out.println("inseq");
        if (waiting) return;
        sequence.add(rand.nextInt(4));
        //System.out.println(next);
        for (final int i : sequence) {
            buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(colors[i]);
                }
            }, 0, 500);
        }
        waiting = true;
        curPos = 0;
    }
    public void makeMove(View view) throws Exception{
        //System.out.println("here");
        if(!waiting) return;
        int move = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        //System.out.println("move " + move);
        if(sequence.get(curPos) == move){
            //System.out.println("Correct move: " + curPos);
            curPos++;
            if(curPos == sequence.size()){
                try{
                    waiting = false;
                    nextInSeq();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for(Button b : buttons){
                b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            start.setText("New Game");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(colors[i]); 
        });
    }
});
```

Personally I would use `Animation` and `AnimationListener` together, `onAnimationEnd` i will resume doing my game logic.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button color which you need to change after 500ms..

```
      new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // this will show after 500ms
        }
    }, 500);
```

Try this:

```
 Button button;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     call();
 }
public void call(){
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            call2();
        }
    }, 1000);

}
public void call2(){
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and the app actually runs now, but I am still running into the issue where multiple buttons will be white at the same time.  Do I need to wait before calling the handler again?

Comment: I have edited my code.the second function will call after 1s... change the time as per your need...